# org-capture to a heading within a date-tree

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

been using org-mode for a little over a year, but still have a ton to learn. Here's the setup and question: i've got a straightforward date-tree daily notes / tasks setup, and i'm trying to figure out how to append to a sub-heading within that structure. At the top-level, my main file is structured like this:

```
* 2020
** 2020-11 November
*** 2020-11 November
**** 2020-11-24 Tuesday
***** tasks
***** log
***** meetings
***** notes
```

And I want to create a capture template that appends a note under today's "* log". I'm currently using a capture template like this:

```
   ("y" "Work Task" entry (file+olp+datetree "~/org/journal/work.org")
    "* TODO %?\n%U" :empty-lines 1)
```

Which is fine, but it adds the task to the date correctly, but not the TASKS sub-heading. Any idea how I'd set that up?

Comment: There is no way to answer the question without a lot more detail about the structure of the file where the capture will end up. If you have a capture template that you are using already, please add it to the question and describe how it fails to satisfy your requiremenets.

Comment: thanks for the response, @nickd. tweaked my writeup above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to search the subtree for the log heading and, if it finds one, set the point to that location.

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("y" "Work Task" entry (file+function
                "~/org/journal/work.org"
                (lambda ()
                  (org-datetree-find-date-create
                   (org-date-to-gregorian (org-today)) t)
                  (re-search-forward "^\\*.+ log" nil t)))
     "* TODO %?\n%U" :empty-lines 1)))
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you!